# Why NSNotification is called many times and view didn't appear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I made a ViewController and set NSNotification.
And if I press the button, the same ViewController that has different labels will appear and the other view (sub class) will appear too.
But NSNotification will be called many times same to how many times I press the button even I remove NSNotification.

If I changed the place to write NSNotification, the view (sub class) didn't appear and sometimes the view will appear soon.
(It should appear after 1 second after back to before ViewController)

Why and how can I solve it?

```
@implementation aViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *bgimgV = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    bgimgV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
    bgimgV.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:bgimgV];

    UIButton* backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    UIImage *backBtnimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    [backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 50, 50);
    [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:backBtn];

    UILabel* questLbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    questLbl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 45, 300, 180);

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",set[0]];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\n"];
    questLbl.text = string;
    questLbl.textColor = RGB(10, 10, 10);
    questLbl.font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"HiraKakuProN-W6" size:15];
    questLbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:questLbl];

    for(int b = 0; b<3; b++){
        answerBtn[b] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        answerBtn[b].frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-(576/2)/2, 290+b*65, 576/2, 90/2);

        [answerBtn[b] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed
                               :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"answer%d.png",b+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        answerBtn[b].tag = b;
        [answerBtn[b] addTarget:self action:@selector(answerBtn BtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview: answerBtn[b]];
     }

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(addView)
                                                 name:@"addView"
                                               object:nil];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"addView"
                                                  object:nil];
}

//when press the back button, add view (sub class)
-(void)backBtnAction:(UIButton*)button{

    if([APP_DELEGATE questTag] == 0){

    }else{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDelegate.questionTag--;
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addView"
                                                        object:nil];

}

//when press answer button, same ViewController will appear and change the label
-(void)answerBtnAction:(UIButton*)button{

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.questTag++;

    double delayInSeconds = 0.3;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
           [self changePage];
    });

}

-(void)changePage{

    aViewController *aVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aVC animated:YES];

}

//After back to before page, view (subclass) will be appear after 1 second
-(void)addView{

    [self performSelector:@selector(viewAppear) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}

-(void)viewAppear{

   self.RecView = [[InsteRecView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,    [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:self.RecView];

}
```

Comment: Looks like retain cycle trouble when using self in that dispatch_after block

Comment: I replaced "dispatch_after block" to "[self performSelector:@selector(changePage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];". But subclass view didn't appear...